# Docker swarm with compose file, set architecture to arm64

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, arm64

I have a problem with a cluster of arm64 machines not starting the containers. All of them stay as 0/2, 0/1 ect. This seem to be due to the scheduling setup to deploy them on amd64 instead of arm64 but I can't find where to change this (I assume there is a docker-compose config for this).

```
$ sudo docker service ls                                                                                                                             1 ↵
ID                  NAME                         MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                                  PORTS
t761cgtu2n4o        persistence_mariadb          replicated          0/1                 mojlighetsministeriet/mariadb-arm64:latest             *:3306->3306/tcp
l1gxlfuwtfs9        services_email               replicated          0/2                 mojlighetsministeriet/email-arm64:latest               
6o1ud2la0eig        services_groups              replicated          0/2                 mojlighetsministeriet/groups-arm64:latest
```

When inspecting a service I get:

```
        "Placement": {                        
            "Platforms": [                    
                {                                                                                                                                                                        
                    "Architecture": "amd64",
                    "OS": "linux"
                }
            ]
        },
```

I'm using docker-compose files to configure the services, how can I mark the images to run on arm64 machines (the images starts fine on the arm64 machines with $ docker run)?

This is an example of the config for one service:

```
  email:
    image: mojlighetsministeriet/email-arm64
    secrets:
      - smtp-password
    environment:
      SMTP_HOST: smtp.example.com
      SMTP_PORT: 587
      SMTP_EMAIL: user@example.com
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
        failure_action: continue
        monitor: 60s
        max_failure_ratio: 0.3
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      labels:
        - traefik.docker.network=proxy
        - traefik.port=80
        - traefik.enable=true
    networks:
      - proxy
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @PabloRomeo I did solve it, but not sure exactly how right now (been a while since I worked on the cluster), it might have been that I used one of these machines to build the images on.

Comment: thanks! I found a way around it, and have posted it here as an answer, for posterity :)

Answer (score 1):

In order for docker images to run on ARM based computers it is necessary for the base image (container) to be ARM based.

You can not tell docker-compose to just run in ARM mode. The actual image must be ARM based.

e.g. here on [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/u/arm32v7/) you can find base images created for ARM based computers

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I use Go for the services so they all use FROM scratch, the images just contains one arm64 binary. Here is one Dockerfile for example https://github.com/mojlighetsministeriet/email/blob/master/arm64.Dockerfile . The image runs fine with docker run on the arm64 machine so I don't think there is anything wrong with the image. It's when I try to configure it with $ docker stack deploy that it won't start and probably since the schedueling architecture gets set to amd64 instead of arm64.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around the same problem, by using the `--resolve-image never` parameter while deploying the stack.

```
docker stack deploy <stack name> --compose-file <compose-file>.yml --resolve-image never
```

The same can be done during `docker service create` using the `--no-resolve-image`